# cron jobs not working: the script php is "Not a directory"!

Tags: php, cron

I try to configure the cron job with a php script (simple script) but not work. this is the error message:
*/bin/sh: /opt/php56/bin/php/home3/visiva/public_html/mydomain.co.uk/script2/invoice.php: Not a directory*

the script is in a folder of domain.
i don't understand what is the problem...

thanks

Comment: Well, one problem is you seem to trying to execute a PHP script with /bin/sh.  You need to provide more details, like your crontab line.

Comment: Where is the cronjob? Can you show us crontab output or similar

Comment: It looks like the PHP interpreter is `/opt/php56/bin/php`, the script you want to run is `/home3/visiva/public_html/mydomain.co.uk/script2/invoice.php` and you forgot to put a space between them in the command line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this cron jobs in two ways:

1. In the first line of script add: `#!/usr/bin/php`
2. In a specific row, after time (this `* * * *`) in crontab set `php PATH_TO_SCRIPT/SCRIPT_NAME.php`